pandas udf RuntimeError: Number of columns of the returned pandas.DataFrame doesn't match specified schema
I'm running a pandas udf as follows:
def some_udf(df, keys = IDS_COLS, cols_to_keep = COLS_TO_KEEP):
    INT_ID_COLUMN = '__iid'

    df_keys = df.select(keys).distinct().withColumn(INT_ID_COLUMN, F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    df = df.join(df_keys, keys)

    pred_df_schema = df.select(INT_ID_COLUMN, *keys, 'tx_id', F.lit(0.0).alias('score'), 'class').schema

    pred_with_some_udf = F.pandas_udf(
        some_func,
        returnType=pred_df_schema,
        functionType=F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP
    )

    prediction_df = df.select(INT_ID_COLUMN, 'tx_id', 'class', *keys ,*cols_to_keep) \
        .groupby(INT_ID_COLUMN) \
        .apply(pred_with_some_udf) \
        .drop(INT_ID_COLUMN)
        
    return prediction_df

and the pandas function is as follows:
def some_func(df):
    ...
    return df[[*keys, 'tx_id', 'score', 'class']]

i keep getting errors saying that:

'RuntimeError: Number of columns of the returned pandas.DataFrame doesn't match specified schema. Expected: 6 Actual: 5'

i can't figure out this error. i clearly state that i'm expecting 6 columns: 1 is the group by key and 5 are the values that each group returns. any ideas how to solve that?

I mean you indeed are missing one column in return - to elaborate on example from official documentation - see that is uses .assign which adds column i.e. all the original columns remain as they were + there's one extra - so grouping column is explicitly returned.
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))

@pandas_udf("id long, v double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def subtract_mean(pdf):
    # pdf is a pandas.DataFrame
    v = pdf.v
    return pdf.assign(v=v - v.mean())

df.groupby("id").apply(subtract_mean).show()

see here doc

thanks! i found and posted the solution. the problem source wasn't exactly what you pointed out but your answer guided me to the solution

apparentely i just had to remove the group by column from the schema. not sure why but when the schema looks like this:
pred_df_schema = df.select(*keys, 'tx_id', F.lit(0.0).alias('score'), 'class').schema

instead of:
pred_df_schema = df.select(INT_ID_COLUMN, *keys, 'tx_id', F.lit(0.0).alias('score'), 'class').schema

it works.
